# Cannot gracefully Shutdown JMeter, Stoptest

Tags: jmeter

I'm running JMeter test via cmd and I want to stop the test/shutdown as I do in the GUI mode, but I cannot do it.
I enter the bin folder and double click shutdown.cmd/stoptest.cmd but I keep receiving this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class testing\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar`

n.b. There is no folder 'testing' in my path. the path is like this:

```
C:\Load testing\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of developers know only a little bit of SDK of one programming language and suck at everything else, particularly here you are suffering from badly written batch file.

The fastest workaround is renaming your "Load testing" folder into "Loadtesting". Going forward when it comes to Java if possible put the application under the path which doesn't contain whitespaces, non-English characters, special symbols, etc. just in case.

The fix is to surround the path to ApacheJmeter.jar with quotation marks like:

```
java -cp "%~dp0ApacheJMeter.jar" org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown %*
```

If possible please report the issue via [JMeter bug tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In general well-behaved JMeter tests don't need to be shut down, they should end after specified amount of loops or according to Thread Group Scheduler or whatever. If the test last longer than expected it indicates that something went wrong. Make sure you're following steps from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article and your JMeter instance(s) are configured optimally.

Comment: This is a great answer! Removing the spaces from my path solved my issue! Thanks! Should I report it to the bug tracker?

Comment: Yes, please, it will help others and make JMeter better